# How to Get CPU Usage as taskmgr? C#

Tags: c#, performancecounter

Using a code like this

```
PerformanceCounter cpu_utilized = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", @"% Processor Time", @"_Total");
CounterSample a1 = cpu_utilized.NextSample();
Thread.Sleep(500); //tried other values, same result
float a = CounterSample.Calculate(a1, cpu_utilized.NextSample());
string str = "CPU USAGE %: " + a;
System.Console.Out.WriteLine(str);
```

The result is the same as perfmon.exe counter, but differs from taskmgr value

I want to get total system cpu usage as show by taskmgr, already tried using just NextValue() instead but the result is the same...

Any suggestions of how to do it? I should find some other counter and add to it or something?

More Info:
I'm using a CPU with 4 physical cores and 8 logical cores
Windows 10
Perfmon shows around 36%
Taskmgr shows around 48%

Answer (score 0):

Paulo, try take a look at [process hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/).
Grab the CPU usage will be one of the problems, the ones that deals with workingset, physical memory, paging, tlb, and so forth are dozen times more complicated.

Source Code has been written in C and not C#. However you can use it easily.
I am not a C# expert, yet I am quite sure that it uses a C API behind the scenes if there is such api for the language.